# Grep-ing non-seekable file

Tags: linux, bash, grep, stdin

How does grep allocate buffer for reading lines when non-seekable files like devices, sockets, pipes or fifos are used?

I tried doing the following

```
grep hello -
```

I gave as input a single line containing around 9484 characters including space. Grep processed some characters (I guess around 4K) and just printed those characters to the screen. The input line did not contain hello (I just repeated the line "One way is to simply treat binary files as text anyway"). There were no error messages, grep just exited.

Is grep supposed to work with non-seekable files? If so how does it manage the buffer?

Edit: Steps to reproduce it.
I copy pasted the 9484 characters from a text editor (sublime text2) into the terminal in ubuntu after I entered

```
grep hello -
```

Then I pressed control+d to end the input.

I am not able to reproduce it using the way "that other guy" mentioned below. It seems to work when I do

```
while printf "One way is to simply treat binary files as text anyway "; do true; done 2> /dev/null | head -c 9484 | grep hello -
```

Comment: it probably allocates a fixed buffer, e.g. 1024 chars, then reads until the input is done (eof) or it fills the buffer. if it's not at eof, then it just keeps looping.

Comment: @MarcB Using a fixed size buffer won't work for grep, because the regex may be required to match a larger portion of the line. You can't give a maximum size for the match of almost any nontrivial regex, so using a fixed limit would drastically decrease the usefulness of the tool (meaning: a user would not be able to trust the tool that it find all possible matches!).

Comment: true enough, but it can take multiple paths depending on what the pattern is like. e.g. `grep 'huge ugly pattern'` will cause different buffering than `grep 'fixed simple string'`.

Comment: I tried reproducing this with: `while printf "One way is to simply treat binary files as text anyway "; do true; done 2> /dev/null | head -c 9484 | grep hello -` .  It writes your sentence over and over until the line is 9484 bytes, and then tries to find "hello". I get no output, as expected. Can you edit your question and include steps to reproduce? Make sure to be explicit, e.g. "middle click the terminal to paste" rather than "give as input", because there are many buffers and limits not related to grep and bash.

Comment: @thatotherguy So how does it allocate the buffer to read a line? If it allocates too less, and say that it reuses the buffer for reading more characters, it won't be able to go back and read the beginning of the line.

Comment: Have you looked into how this varies if you use grep options that don't require it to be able to print the line in which a match occurred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep`, like many other unix tools, works based on lines. That is, it never has to keep more than exactly one line in memory. There are two ways to handle this:

1. A single buffer is (re)used, and grown whenever a line is encountered that does not fit in this buffer.
2. The `grep`-like tool uses the `readline()` function.

The first alternative may be a little more efficient, the second one is definitely more convenient.

Comment: I think grep is growing the buffer (may be using realloc?) as you mentioned in point 1. I was watching the grep process using top as it was scanning through a single line containing 10 million characters - the memory footprint was gradually growing. When I tried using 1billion characters, grep reported "memory exhausted" (I am using 1GB of DRAM for the machine that I ran the tests).

Answer (score 2):

As the piped example shows, `grep` is more than happy to match any length input from unseekable sources. GNU grep in particular allows arbitrary line lengths.

The problem you're seeing is instead the terminal's line buffer filling up when you paste long lines. This buffer is [4096 bytes](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/tty.h#L308).

You can disable line buffering with `stty -icanon` in that terminal, and see that `grep` now happily  matches any line you paste, regardless of its length.

Make sure to-renable with `stty icanon` or `reset` after testing, because line buffering is what allows you to use backspace in most CLI programs.

Comment: With stty -icanon, backspace and control+d is not working. But grep works as expected! Thanks!